# How To setup Azure DNS server

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, nameservers

I want to change name-server of my domain, but Azure websites services only offer CNAME and not name-server, Somebody told me we can host our DNS on Azure using virtual machine,, So anybody here which can provide all steps to create DNS server on Azure and how to setup name-servers out of it?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but more a suggestion.

You can host your DNS records in Azure using Azure DNS (currently in public preview).

Here are some more information about the service https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/dns/ and steps required to get the service working https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-getstarted-create-dnszone/.